# How to configure postfix to replace the name of the sender to a configured one

Tags: email, postfix

I have `postfix` installed on my machine. I also use the `generic` maps to overwrite the email address from `ubuntu` to `admin@example.com`:

```
/etc/postfix/generic
    ubuntu     admin@example.com
```

With this generic mapping the email comes from `"Ubuntu" <admin@example.com>`. But I also want to overwrite the the **From Name** of the sender to `Server1` such that I receive emails from: `"Server1" <admin@example.com>`.

How do I configure this in `postfix`?

Comment: I edited it to make it more clear. Better now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the `MTA` uses the configuration that are in the system, so if your username 'ubuntu' does not have any full name setted, then all e-mails from him will came without a name, or perhaps the name that you've setted on 'ubuntu' login is just "Ubuntu" since you said that all e-mails are coming with `"Ubuntu" <admin@example.com"`

To fix that, try use this command as root, and then send e-mail again

```
# chfn -f "Server1" ubuntu
```

Hope it helps ;)