# How can I strip or rewrite the sender's name of a from address when using postfix?

Tags: centos, postfix

### Objective

I'm trying to configure a CentOS 7 system so all mail sent to local system accounts gets redirected to an alternate email address.  For example, if mail is sent to `root` I want it to be redirected to `sysadmins@example.com`.

I have a mostly working configuration using postfix, generic maps, and aliases.  If the complete configuration I'm using will help, ask and I'll modify the question to include it.

If there's a better way of accomplishing my objective, please tell me.  I'd prefer to stick with postfix, but only because it's the default MTA on CentOS.

### Problem

I'm trying to configure postfix as a smart host so I can relay mail via a ZOHO account.  However, ZOHO is **extremely** picky about the format of the from address.

When I try to send mail with a sender address that looks like this, it works:

```
noreply@example.com
```

However, when I try to send mail with a sender address that looks like this, it fails:

```
noreply@example.com (Ryan)
```

### Examples

Below are 4 examples sent using the exact same postfix configuration.

#### Allowed

I use this command:

```bash
mail -r "noreply@example.com" -s "Testing." root <<< "Test to root."
```

...and see this in `maillog` (I've stripped the message down and reformatted it to make it a bit more readable):

```
CD9FA29D20: from=<noreply@example.com>
CD9FA29D20: to=<sysadmins@example.com>,
    orig_to=<root>,
    relay=smtp.zoho.com[74.201.154.90]:587,
    delay=2.4,
    delays=0/0.02/1.7/0.66, dsn=2.0.0,
    status=sent (250 Message received)
```

#### Allowed

I use this command:

```bash
mail -r "Ryan <noreply@example.com>" -s "Testing." root <<< "Test to root."
```

...and see this in `maillog` (I've stripped the message down and reformatted it to make it a bit more readable):

```
936C929D20: from=<noreply@example.com>
936C929D20: to=<sysadmins@example.com>,
    orig_to=<root>,
    relay=smtp.zoho.com[74.201.154.90]:587,
    delay=2.3,
    delays=0/0.03/1.6/0.7,
    dsn=2.0.0,
    status=sent (250 Message received)
```

#### Relaying Denied

I use this command:

```bash
mail -r "noreply@example.com (Ryan)" -s "Testing." root <<< "Test to root."
```

...and see this in `maillog` (I've stripped the message down and reformatted it to make it a bit more readable):

```
D57C529D20: from=<noreply@example.com>
D57C529D20: to=<sysadmins@example.com>,
    orig_to=<root>,
    relay=smtp.zoho.com[74.201.154.90]:587,
    delay=2,
    delays=0.01/0/1.4/0.64,
    dsn=5.0.0,
    status=bounced (host smtp.zoho.com[74.201.154.90] said:
        553 Relaying disallowed as noreply@example.com (Ryan) (in reply to end of DATA command))
```

#### Relaying Denied

I use this command:

```bash
mail -s "Testing." root <<< "Test to root."
```

...and see this in `maillog` (I've stripped the message down and reformatted it to make it a bit more readable):

```
9CFE629D20: from=<ryan@localhost.localnet>
9CFE629D20: to=<sysadmins@example.com>,
    orig_to=<root>,
    relay=smtp.zoho.com[74.201.154.90]:587,
    delay=2,
    delays=0/0.02/1.4/0.6,
    dsn=5.0.0,
    status=bounced (host smtp.zoho.com[74.201.154.90] said:
        553 Relaying disallowed as noreply@example.com (Ryan) (in reply to end of DATA command))
```

### Question

It's the last example that I'm having trouble with since the default when not explicitly including the address is to write the address in a way that ZOHO will reject.

Is it possible to have postfix strip or rewrite a person's name when rewriting a sender address?  There's a similar question to [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/659122/how-to-configure-postfix-to-replace-the-name-of-the-sender-to-a-configured-one), but it doesn't accomplish what I want.  I don't want to rely on changing user account settings to ensure my mail doesn't get bounced.

Comment: The normally accepted format for the from address is `Ryan <noreply@example.com>`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes, I forgot to mention that I'm able to use that format successfully.  I added an example to show that format works.  I also added an example that shows how omitting the sender address using `mail` will cause it to be written the way that ZOHO rejects.  Maybe there's some `mail` configuration that I've missed.

Comment: In that case I would check your `~/.mailrc` and environment variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to solving this is understanding how the postfix `cleanup` process handles missing header information.  From the [cleanup man page:](http://www.postfix.org/cleanup.8.html)

```
The cleanup(8) daemon always performs the following transformations:

   o      Insert missing  message  headers:  (Resent-)  From:,  To:,  Mes-
          sage-Id:, and Date:.
```

An [old mailing list post](http://marc.info/?l=postfix-users&m=113390611925821&w=2) give's a hint about the formatting of inserted `From` headers:

```
The defaults are:

MAIL FROM address = UNIX login name
FROM: header = UNIX login name (GECOS information)
```

Since it's the header information that needs to be changed or reformatted, using postfix's `header_checks` seems like the obvious solution.  However, it doesn't work.  Reading the [header_checks man page](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html) there's another hint in the `BUGS` section.

```
Message headers added by the cleanup(8) daemon itself are excluded from
inspection.  Examples  of  such  message  headers  are From:, To:, Mes-
sage-ID:, Date:.
```

There's [another mailing list thread](http://marc.info/?t=144040968700021&r=1&w=2) with someone else trying to solve the same problem and they end up using `smtp_header_checks`.  There isn't a lot of documentation for `smtp_header_checks`, but, since the processing is applied when mail is delivered via SMTP, it can be used to rewrite the `From` header added by `cleanup`.

Here's an example of an `/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks` configuration that will change the `From` (header) address of **every outgoing message** to `LOCALHOST System <noreply@example.com>`:

```
/^From:.*/ REPLACE From: LOCALHOST System <noreply@example.com>
```

Please note I'm not a regex expert, so you may want to [test your own regex](https://regex101.com/) rather than relying on the one above.

After adding `smtp_header_checks`, the following config option must be added to `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
smtp_header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks
```

Then reload the postfix config (assuming `systemd`) and send a test message:

```bash
sudo systemctl reload postfix
```

```bash
sendmail me@example.com << EOF
Subject: Test email to root.

Testing.
EOF
```

Answer (score 3):

It is fairly common that mail servers require a valid e-mail address and reject invalid ones.

```
 noreply@example.com (Ryan)
```

is not a valid e-mail address. The [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address) has some useful pointers, as well as references to the relevant RFC's.

In practice you use either a bare email address:

```
noreply@example.com
```

or whatever display name followed by a mailbox enclosed with <kbd><</kbd><kbd>></kbd> such as:

```
Ryan <noreply@example.com>
```

Comment: The problem I'm having is that `mail` (`heirloom-mailx`) will use the incorrect format for the from address if I don't explicitly add it with `-r`.  I added a couple more examples to my question to make it more clear.

Comment: That erroneous from address probably gets picked up from either your environment variables (in bash check with `env` and/or `set`) or your `~/.mailrc`  rather than your postfix, although postfix can be modified to do a [quite a bit of rewriting](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html)  too.